# Node.js domains in Express app middleware

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-domains

I believe the following code might be useful to handle exceptions that occur to certain requests:

```
var domain = require('domain');

app.use(function(req,res,next){

    var d = domain.create();

    d.on('error',function(err){
      res.json({error: err.stack});
    });

    d.run(function(){
       next();
    });

});
```

however, I read that this type of code can leak memory. I am not sure I understand why. Is there a way to avoid leaking memory? Perhaps I should manually remove all the event handling and listeners for the domain after the response stream is closed? How do I allow the domain object to be garbage collected?

Comment: Also, I read that the domain core module will be deprecated, and I am curious as to what might replace it as it seems that the domain module is quite useful

Comment: Where did you read that this type of code can leak memory? Perhaps the author knows why.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html

Comment: I assume it leaks memory because for every request that comes in, the domain object is created, and it keeps listening for error events forever, so never gets GC'ed

Comment: Actually the domain object will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as `next()` returns - the execution stack will unwind and there will be no more references to `d` anywhere. The attached event listener is part of `d` so it will be gc'ed together with the domain.

Comment: Leaking memory is mainly an issue if you ignore errors, as domains stop the script from throwing, and just keeps on going, regardless of fatal errors that may cause huge memory build ups. You shouldn't really use domains for something simple like this at all, but read up on error handling in Node instead of wrapping code that may fail in a domain just for the heck of it.

Comment: I actually think domains are good for this most basic use case. This way if an uncaught exception happens, it will immediately send back a response to the requestor. Otherwise what will happen is that the request will timeout on the other end because the server will never send back a response. However, I do think that Express middleware might already have this covered.

Comment: unless I am mistaken?

Comment: I've yet to find a case where using a domain was better than making sure you have proper error handling at the source of the error.

Comment: @jfriend00  - you can't put a try/catch around an async callback. Such that if you throw an error in the async callback function, it can't get caught TMK. Express must have some built-in mechanism to handle errors that get caught otherwise. I am guessing it's similar to the way "domain" works.

Comment: @AlexMills - the ONLY way to properly handle exceptions in async code is to handle it IN the async code, not from the top level.  The domain mechanism is basically a hack that can leak and not clean up resources properly (like leave file handles open, etc...).  That's why promises are so incredibly valuable for async operations.  They catch exceptions at every level and turn them into rejected promises which you write code to handle properly.  There is NO shortcut for proper error handling at every level that can create an error.

Comment: that makes some good sense, I believe you on all counts